# Using VBA in Microsoft Publisher, is it possible to set the image of a "Picture Placeholder"

Tags: vba, placeholder, publisher

I created a template in Microsoft Publisher, which has a few "Picture Placeholders" on it.  I have read through the documentation, but cannot figure out how to programmatically set the image of my placeholders.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes

    If shp.AlternativeText = "Image1" Then
        ' I want to set the image here, something like shp.Image = "C:\blah.jpg"
        Debug.Print ("Got to image 1")
    ElseIf shp.AlternativeText = "Image2" Then
        Debug.Print ("Got to image 2")

    Else


    End If

    Next shp


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the answer, I was able to figure it out:

```
shp.PictureFormat.ReplaceEx ("FilePath")
```